# Apache 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, lamp

I have apache 2.4.23 installed on my elementary os freya(Ubuntu 14.04). i installed it as a LAMP stack...
I keep getting the 403 permission denied error any time i tried to run http://localhost on my browser.
I have my apache2.conf configured like this:

```
<Directory /media/windisk/xampp/htdocs>
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

i find on some sites that i should run this code to change the permission okf the folder:

```
sudo chown bosunski:www-data /media/windisk/xampp/htdocs
sudo chmod -R 755 /media/windisk/xampp/htdocs
chmod -R g+rwX /media/windisk/xampp/htdocs/
```

I ran all this commands but the error is still there. please is there anything i've been missing? OR How can i correct this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to allow Apache to access the root folder of your LAMP files:
See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110179/adding-virtualhost-fails-access-forbidden-error-403-xampp-windows-7

Edit the conf file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/yourconffile.conf

Enter following:

```
<VirtualHost localhost:80>  
 DocumentRoot "/path/to/your/rootfolder"  
        <Directory "/path/to/your/rootfolder">  
            # AllowOverride All      # Deprecated  
        # Order Allow,Deny       # Deprecated  
        # Allow from all         # Deprecated  
        # --New way of doing it  
        Require all granted    
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```